# Reset Google Chrome setting without lost all data

Tags: google-chrome

As the title says it all, I want to reset Google Chrome setting without loss of data, such as bookmarks, active logins, history, extensions etc. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Choose **Advance Sync Settings** and their unmark the option **Settings** so from here they will not sync yo your email account, then Sign out form your account and reset and then again login, hope this will help.

Comment: I guess this is how, because I've tried to reset and sync but no luck.

Comment: You mean you have already tried this method, right?

Comment: I tried the way provided by @dashboard, I have not tried your way because I was afraid of losing active login and cookies.

Comment: Old question bumped by Community around 10 times. "As the title says it all, ", actually it doesn't say all. in a comment from 2013 the OP mentions to have tried what was suggested in th answer posted 10 years ago but it's not clear if that worked or not, if that not worked there aren't enouth details to help to troubleshoot the problem. Missing details, name and version of the operative system, version of Chrome, if the OP have a Google account, the type of Google account, consumer or nowadays Google Workspace account, if it's a consumer account, if it uses  Gmail address as the primary email

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to Google Chrome then sync your browser with your email address
next reset Google Chrome and sign in with the same email and sync everything back.